# Incorrect syntax near ')'. SQL query is wrong while running on both DBeaver and on java mapper files?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, dbeaver

```
  DECLARE @source as NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT md.[source] FROM sports_service.meet.meet_detail md WHERE md.meet_id = #{meetId})

    WHERE reg.is_waitlist = 0 AND reg.cancelled_dt IS NULL 
          AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM sports_service.meet.meet_invitations i
            WHERE i.meet_id = pmm.meet_id AND i.sports_person_id = reg.sports_person_id) 
     IF @source != 'MANUAL'
          AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM sports_service.meet.session session
                INNER JOIN sports_service.meet.event event ON event.session_id = session.id 
                WHERE pmm.meet_id = session.meet_id
                    AND sports_service.dbo.fnGetMeetAge(p.birth_dt, detail.age_up_date, detail.id_format) <![CDATA[>=]]> event.low_age
                    AND sports_service.dbo.fnGetMeetAge(p.birth_dt, detail.age_up_date, detail.id_format) <![CDATA[<=]]> event.high_age
                    AND (event.eligible_gender IS NULL OR event.eligible_gender = p.gender))
```

Comment: looks like you made an error in your sql, but seriously, this is way too vague to check.

Comment: Why does your query have both Ruby and HTML artifacts?

Comment: Remove the `)` in `#{meetId})`

Comment: ruakh please only focus on my sql condition check statement IF @source != 'MANUAL' is this correct or not?

Comment: Can you post full error message. Also post SQL code which passed to SQL driver without XML escaping and other stuff.

Comment: When can you start an Sql statement with `WHERE` (`WHERE reg.is_waitlist = 0`...`)?

Comment: To answer my own question, I now see that the query has been edited in a way that makes it incomplete and incorrect.

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL to begin with. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check some condition (`AND EXISTS ...` clause) only if some other condition holds (source is `MANUAL`) and you want to do that in one query instead of:

```
WHERE (...some condition ...) AND (.. some other condition ... )
IF @source != 'MANUAL'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 ... )
```

which is not supported as it is not a correct sql syntax you can do:

```
WHERE (...some condition ...) AND (.. some other condition ... )
    AND (
       (
         (SELECT md.[source] 
          FROM sports_service.meet.meet_detail md 
          WHERE md.meet_id = #{meetId}
         ) = 'MANUAL'
       )
      OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM ...
      )
    )
```

You need to check if the performance of the resulting query would be satisfactory.

It would be probably better to execute the query that gets the `source` first and then execute either query with the additional condition or without it depending on the `source` value. To do that you can generate the query in mybatis using [dynamic SQL](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) (including or excluding this additional condition).

Answer (score 1):

As you can't use If inside expression, you can write your sql like this:

```
DECLARE @source as NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT md.[source] FROM sports_service.meet.meet_detail md WHERE md.meet_id = #{meetId})

    WHERE reg.is_waitlist = 0 AND reg.cancelled_dt IS NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
    1
    FROM
    sports_service.meet.meet_invitations i
    WHERE
    i.meet_id = pmm.meet_id
    AND i.sports_person_id = reg.sports_person_id)
    AND ( @source <> 'MANUAL' 
    AND 
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM
    sports_service.meet.session session
    INNER JOIN sports_service.meet.event event ON
    event.session_id = session.id
    WHERE
    pmm.meet_id = session.meet_id
    AND sports_service.dbo.fnGetMeetAge(p.birth_dt,
    detail.age_up_date,
    detail.id_format) >= event.low_age
    AND sports_service.dbo.fnGetMeetAge(p.birth_dt,
    detail.age_up_date,
    detail.id_format) <= event.high_age
    AND (event.eligible_gender IS NULL
    OR event.eligible_gender = p.gender)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `IF` inside expression.